# How to open a component in another window with React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a component page open in another window when I click a button. I have tried using `window.open(<Contact />)`, however that does not seem to work.

I am trying to make it so that the `<button>Contact me!</button>` opens that component in a full window. Is there a way to do that?

**ContactMe.jsx:**

```
import '../App.css';
import Contact from './Contact';
import { ReactComponent as LinkedInLogo } from '../images/linkedin.svg';

function ContactMe() {

    return(
        <>
        <div className='contact-container' id='contactMe'>
            <div className='contact-box'>
                <h1>Want to connect?</h1>
                <button id='contact-me-btn'>Contact Me!</button>
                <a>
                    <LinkedInLogo title='LinkedIn Profile' id='linkedinprofile-svg'/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className='contact-container-footer'>
                <h7>Designed and built by <a href='https://github.com/BlazingIsFire' target='_blank' title='Github'>Andrew Schweitzer</a>.</h7>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )   
}

export default ContactMe;
```

Comment: I think you will have to add a router, add that component as a route and open that route with `_blank`. I don't think that there is other alternative

Comment: I currently use router for the mobile version of the page.

Answer (score 1):

First create Route for the component tab

```
<Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />}> // if you are using router v6
```

To open the link in a new tab, use the  element by passing a target attribute with a value `_blank`. Like this

```
<a href="/Contact" target="_blank"> <button>Contact Me </button></a>
```

Comment: If you want to use inside a function, you can use in this way  `window.open("/Contact");`. But you have to define Route first.

Comment: That does work, it makes a new section. But I want it to be the whole page, how do I do that?